# PHP readfile() which preserves mime-type

Tags: php, mime-types

I am trying to set up a PHP script which can pull files (for validated users) from a folder outside of the live webroot. The problem is that when doing this, even if I use a proper "Content-Type" header, the file is downloaded as `application/octet-stream`. This has security implications if the user later tries to re-upload the downloaded file as it will be detected as an application even when it is really a pdf (my application only allows certain mime-types to be uploaded).

This is what I am using to pull the file into the browser:

```
$secret_file = "../attach/1/test.pdf";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($secret_file));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"test.pdf\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($secret_file);
```

Interestingly, if I download the file this way through a browser and view its properties in linux, it shows up as "application/pdf". However, if I check the same file using PHP's `mime_content_type()` function, it reads as `application/octet-stream`.

I did confirm that checking the original file this way (before it is pulled through `readfile`) shows it as `application/pdf`.

Is there any way to use `readfile()` without changing mime types? Or, is there perhaps a better alternative?

**EDIT**

Answering some questions from the comments:

1. Developer Tools in Firefox reports that the inline file has a `Content-Type: application/pdf` header.
2. sha256sum of downloaded file does not match the original file. But how could `readfile()` (or similar) be used without changing the file?

Comment: What is `mime_content_type` returning? "This has security implications if the user later tries to re-upload the downloaded file as it will be detected as an application even when it is really a pdf." No, that's not how it works.

Comment: mime_content_type returns "application/pdf" on the original file, then later it returns "application/octet-stream" after it is downloaded through readfile. Well, in my application, that is actually how it works because I only allow certain mime types to be uploaded. I don't want people uploading random executables and such.

Comment: mime types aren't usually tagged onto a file, but instead assumed from the file extension. So what you're asking isn't particularly related to what you assume.

Comment: it is pretty easy to rename "trojan.exe" to "cuddlybunny.jpg". I suppose it might be just as basic to spoof a mime type, but still seems more thorough to rely on that rather than simple extensions.

Comment: `mime_content_type` relies on your system's MIME magic file to be set up correctly, and reads the content of the file to guess at the file type. Downloading it does not change the content, and would not change how it's detected.

Comment: 1) Have you checked with your browser's dev tools to see what headers get *actually* sent. 2) have you checked with sha sums or similar to see if you *really* get the same file or if it actually gets mangled during transport...

Comment: @miken32 I would have guessed the same, but this is unfortunately not the case. I confirmed that mime_content_type reads differently (on the same server) before download and after download. Maybe you aren't accounting for what happens when `readfile()` is used -- it isn't exactly like downloading from a direct link.

Comment: And 3) if your chosen webserver supports it, have you tried `X-SendFile`?

Comment: It reads the file and outputs it. That's all. It doesn't change the content and that's how MIME type is determined.

Comment: @user268396 1) firefox reports content-type: application/pdf, 2) sha256sum does not match, but should it since it is reading the contents of the original file into the browser? But this goes back to the original question - how would this be accomplished _without_ changing the file? 3) Looking at it, not sure how to implement yet

Comment: @Jakumi if mime types are assumed based on file extensions, why would mime_content_type("test.pdf") return "application/octet-stream"? I'm not making assumptions - just reporting actual results. I find them surprising as well, which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Can you post your implementation of mime_content_type()?

Comment: should be https://php.net/mime_content_type , sometimes, mime types can be guessed from magic bytes at the files beginning. But application/octet-stream is probably the most generic one ...

Comment: @Louis Intenthron I believe it is included in my question already - `header("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($secret_file));` - the other side of that is I'm just running a one-line php script to check the content type before and after: `echo mime_content_type('test.pdf');`